# CrossCurrentActivity is null in dependency even though it is initialized and not null in app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, plugins, xamarin.android, dependencies

In my [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms) project, I am using [Plugin.FirebaseAuth](https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth) to log in by phone number.

It works fine for the iOS project, but for Android, the VerifyPhoneNumberAsync() call

```
await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumberAsync(CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance, user.PhoneNumber);
```

is throwing "current activity is null" from the `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity ??` check in https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth/blob/master/Plugin.FirebaseAuth.Android/PhoneAuthProviderWrapper.cs

Plugin.CurrentActivity is initialized (formerly in MainActivity.cs but now in MainApplication.cs as recommended) with no errors as per instructions in https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin:

MainActivity.cs OnCreate():

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

MainApplication.cs OnCreate():

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this);
```

I get the same null error when I call VerifyPhoneNumberAsync() regardless of where I initialize CurrentActivity.

Adding the

```
var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity ?? throw new NullReferenceException("current activity is null");
```

line in my MainActivity.cs directly throws no error.

Is there anything else I could be overlooking?

### Dependency Versions

- Plugin.FirebaseAuth 1.1.2
- Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991265

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: For me, it just started working after upgrading to newer dependency versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither of the previously suggested solutions worked in my scenario.  However, the issue resolved itself after upgrading multiple dependencies, including:

- Plugin.FirebaseAuth 3.1.0
- Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.800

Answer (score 3):

Instead of init method just assign the MainActivity to the plugin current activity.

Try below solution to set the current activity.

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

Replace with

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
```

I had the same issue. I have fixed that issue by applying the same working solution in my case.

Comment: Thank you for sharing!  Alas, it didn't work in my case, but I hope it helps someone else who stumbles across this post.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin doesn't work in your project .

You could try the following code

```
//current activity
var currentActivity= Android.App.Activity;

//current context
var currentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
```